Why is my token rotation not working with auth.js in nextjs 14
I am trying to create a project with nextjs 14 app router. In my project I have used next-auth(5) or auth.js for authentication and authorization. So everything works fine with auth.js but facing a problem with access token expiry time. Though auth.js handle our authentication and authorization for each request .But I want to customize only for credentials. I have set two types (access token and refresh token) of tokens for authentication.In access token I have set access token expiry time 20 seconds. But after successfull login in jwt callbacks access token expiry time set with default expiry time (30 days). So how can I customize the access token expiry value in jwt callbacks?  Below I provide the files responsible with authentication and authorization..
auth.js file
    import bcrypt from "bcryptjs";
    import NextAuth, { AuthError } from "next-auth";
    import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
    import FacebookProvider from "next-auth/providers/facebook";
    import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
    import { authConfig } from "./auth.config";
    import { User } from "./models/user-model";
    
    import { getNewTokens } from "./lib/getNewTokens";
    import { refreshAccessToken } from "./lib/refreshAccessToken";
    
    class customError extends AuthError {
      constructor(message) {
        super();
        this.message = message;
      }
    }
    
    export const {
      handlers: { GET, POST },
      auth,
      signIn,
      signOut,
    } = NextAuth({
      ...authConfig,
      providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
          async authorize(credentials) {
            if (!credentials) return null;
    
            try {
              // Find the user based on the email provided
              const user = await User.findOne({ email: credentials.email }).lean();
              if (!user) {
                console.error("User not found");
                throw new Error("Invalid email or password");
              }
    
              // Compare the entered password with the stored password hash
              const isPasswordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(
                credentials.password,
                user?.password
              );
              if (!isPasswordMatch) {
                console.error("Password mismatch");
                throw new Error("Invalid email or password");
              }
    
              // Return the user object if authentication is successful
              return user;
            } catch (error) {
              // Log and throw the error to be caught in the calling function
              throw new customError(error.message);
            }
          },
        }),
        GoogleProvider({
          clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
          clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
          authorization: {
            params: {
              prompt: "consent",
              access_type: "offline",
              response_type: "code",
            },
          },
        }),
        FacebookProvider({
          clientId: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID,
          clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET,
        }),
      ],
      trustHost:
        process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? true : ["localhost", "127.0.0.1"],
    
      callbacks: {
        async signIn({ user, account, profile }) {
          if (account.provider === "google" || account.provider === "facebook") {
            try {
              const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email: user.email });
              if (!existingUser) {
                const newUser = new User({
                  email: user.email,
                  name: user.name,
                  password: "sample password",
                  role: "customer",
                });
                await newUser.save();
              }
              return true;
            } catch (error) {
              console.error("Error saving user to the database:", error);
              return false;
            }
          }
          return true;
        },
    
        async jwt({ token, user, account }) {
          const currentTime = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
          const accessTokenExpirationTime = 20;
          const refreshTokenExpirationTime = 3600;
          // First time logging in (account and user exist)
          if (user && account) {
            console.log({ user, account, tokenInsideJWT: token });
            // For credentials login
            if (account.provider === "credentials") {
              const newToken = await getNewTokens({
                userId: user.id || user._id.toString(),
                name: user.firstName + user.lastName,
                email: user.email,
              });
    
              return {
                ...token,
                accessToken: newToken?.accessToken,
                refreshToken: newToken?.refreshToken,
                iat: currentTime,
                exp: currentTime + accessTokenExpirationTime,
                refreshTokenExpires: currentTime + refreshTokenExpirationTime,
                provider: account.provider,
                user,
              };
            }
    
            // For social login (Google, Facebook, etc.)
            return {
              ...token,
              accessToken: account.access_token,
              refreshToken: account.refresh_token,
              iat: currentTime,
              exp: currentTime + accessTokenExpirationTime,
              refreshTokenExpires: currentTime + refreshTokenExpirationTime,
              provider: account.provider,
              user,
            };
          }
    
          // Token refresh: Check if the access token has expired
          if (Date.now() / 1000 > token.exp) {
            const refreshedToken = await refreshAccessToken(token);
            console.log(
              "Access token has expired, refreshedTokens...",
              refreshedToken
            );
            return {
              ...refreshedToken,
              exp: currentTime + accessTokenExpirationTime,
              refreshTokenExpires: currentTime + refreshTokenExpirationTime,
            };
          }
    
          console.log({ token }); // **Here I got the default value (30 days) of access token expiry time**
    
          // If the token is valid, ensure the custom expiration is maintained
          // Here we explicitly ensure that the exp is updated every time, even if the token already exists
          if (token && token?.exp) {
            return {
              ...token,
              exp: currentTime + accessTokenExpirationTime, // Force the 20-second expiration on   each call
            };
          }
    
          return token;
        },
    
        async session({ session, token }) {
          console.log({ token }); // **Here I got the customize value (20 sec) of access token expiry time**
          const date = new Date(token?.exp * 1000);
          const options = {
            timeZone: "Asia/Dhaka",
            year: "numeric",
            month: "long",
            day: "numeric",
            hour: "2-digit",
            minute: "2-digit",
            second: "2-digit",
          };
    
          if (token) {
            session.user = token?.user;
            session.accessToken = token?.accessToken;
            session.error = token?.error;
            session.expires = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US", options).format(
              date
            );
          }
    
          return session;
        },
      },
    });
    

if access token expired within 20 seconds I want to regenrate access token as well as refresh token. For this I have created a refreshAccessToken function and this works perfectly.....
    export async function refreshAccessToken(token) {
      let url = null;
      if (token?.provider === "credentials") {
        url =
          `http://localhost:3000/api/auth/refreshToken?` +
          new URLSearchParams({
            grant_type: "refresh_token",
            refresh_token: token?.refreshToken,
          });
      }
    
      if (token?.provider === "google") {
        url =
          `https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token?` +
          new URLSearchParams({
            client_id: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
            client_secret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
            grant_type: "refresh_token",
            refresh_token: token?.refreshToken,
          });
      }
    
      try {
        const response = await fetch(url, {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
          },
          method: "POST",
        });
        const refreshedTokens = await response.json();
    
        if (response?.status !== 200 || !response.ok) {
          throw refreshedTokens;
        }
    
        console.log({ refreshedTokensInsideRefresh: refreshedTokens });
        return {
          ...token,
          accessToken:
            refreshedTokens?.accessToken || refreshedTokens?.access_token,
          refreshToken:
            refreshedTokens?.refreshToken || refreshedTokens?.refreshToken,
        };
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return {
          ...token,
          error: "RefreshAccessTokenError",
        };
      }
    }

this function responsible for creating new tokens....
    import { SignJWT } from "jose";
    
    // Function to generate tokens
    export const getNewTokens = async (user) => {
      const secretKey = new TextEncoder().encode(process.env.AUTH_SECRET);
    
      const currentDate = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {
        timeZone: "Asia/Dhaka",
      });
      const timestamp = new Date(currentDate).getTime();
      const nowInSeconds = Math.floor(timestamp / 1000);
    
      const payload = {
        id: user.userId,
        email: user.email,
        name: user.name,
      };
    
      // Access token (expires in 1 hour)
      const accessToken = await new SignJWT({ ...payload, type: "access" })
        .setProtectedHeader({ alg: "HS256" })
        .setIssuedAt(nowInSeconds)
        .setExpirationTime("20s") // 1 hour from now
        .sign(secretKey);
    
      // Refresh token (expires in 1 day)
      const refreshToken = await new SignJWT({ ...payload, type: "refresh" })
        .setProtectedHeader({ alg: "HS256" })
        .setIssuedAt(nowInSeconds)
        .setExpirationTime("1h") // 1 day from now
        .sign(secretKey);
    
      return { accessToken, refreshToken };
    };
    



I want to customize the default token of auth.js and set expiry time for each of tokens (access token and refresh token)
